# How could a trigger be deployed without any test code?

Tags: apex

I've inherited an org with lots of problems. In production, there's a trigger without any test coverage. How is it possible, that it was deployed in the first place?

Comment: I defiantly sure there are any other test class that covering the trigger code. I suggest run all the org test class and check the trigger coverage again then you will able understand the trigger get covered by other test classes

Comment: That is not an enviable position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce requires at least "1%" coverage for triggers to be deployed. There is an exception, however-- a trigger with 0 lines of actual code will be considered 100% covered, even though it will display as 0% covered. If the trigger did have at least one line of code, then it must have had at least one line of coverage when it was originally deployed.

So, there's two possible scenarios: (a) the trigger never required coverage, or (b) it used to have coverage but now it doesn't because of an administrative change.

The first one we've already talked about, but the second one is a little trickier. To get this condition to exist, all you need to do is write enough test coverage to get the trigger into production, and then change the system so that the unit test can no longer insert/update/delete/undelete the record.

Take this hypothetical trigger:

```
trigger EnsureContactsOnAccount on Account (after update) {
    Set<Id> accountsWithContacts = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT AccountId Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.new]
    ).keySet();
    for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
        if(!accountsWithContacts.contains(record.Id)) {
            record.addError('Please add a contact before updating this account.');
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's consider a simple unit test:

```
@isTest static void testAccountTrigger() {
    try {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
        insert a;
        update a;
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

This unit test would get 100% coverage out of the box, assuming no customization to the org.

Later, some administrator comes along and adds a Universally Required custom field to meet some business need. They don't bother updating unit tests, and this test "looks" okay because it passes when run.

However, the trigger now has 0% coverage. Why? Because the unit test gets to the line "insert a", the database determines that there's a missing required field, and throws a DmlException. The catch block swallows the DML exception, so the trigger gets no coverage, *and* the unit test doesn't fail.

There's other equally likely scenarios that could have occurred. Perhaps a custom validation rule was added, or a required lookup filter. Poorly written tests that aim only for coverage will frequently end up masking administrative changes, and that usually means you'll end up not being able to deploy when you'd *really* like to.

Unfortunately, at this point, it means you probably need to read each test thoroughly to determine which test should have tested the trigger, and why it's failing now.

You might consider using the [source code scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner) to get a report of unit tests that are missing "assert" statements. While this isn't foolproof, or you might find that *no* unit tests have assert statements at all, this may help you track down which test should have been responsible for testing the trigger.

Comment: Oh what an ugly test method. I wish I could say I've never seen similar in the wild. /shudder

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have an entire *project* that has unit tests like this. And, of course, we "don't have time" to fix any of it. Of course, my boss told me I could choose to do it on my own time, unpaid, on the weekends... *sigh*

Comment: Nightmares... One thing I don't miss about consulting.

Comment: well @sfdcfox, you just made a grown man cry over here, lol

Answer (score 1):

Test classes for other classes, other triggers would have covered the test coverage for your trigger, very much possible!

If an `insert` is written in a test class for this object in any other test class, then the insert part code of this trigger will be covered.  Similarly any `update` of this object record in any test class would have covered the update part of this trigger.

So, it could have been easily deployed earlier!